# Why is Rust NLL not working for multiple borrows in the same statement?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

First, I tried something like this:

```
let mut vec = vec![0];
vec.rotate_right(vec.len());
```

It can't be compiled because:

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vec` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

I thought that the Rust borrow checker could be smarter than this, so I found something called **NLL**, and it should solve this problem.

I tried the sample:

```
let mut vec = vec![0];
vec.resize(vec.len(), 0);
```

It could work, but why is it not working with `rotate_right`? Both of them take a `&mut self`. What's going on?

Comment: The difference is that the first one desugars to `[_]::rotate_right (DerefMut::deref_mut (&mut vec), Vec::len (&vec))` while the second one desugars to `Vec::Resize (&mut vec, Vec::len (&vec), 0`. The extra call to `deref_mut` is probably the reason why the borrow checker refuses the first case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is definitely an interesting one.

They are similar - but not quite the same. [`resize()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize) is a member of `Vec`. [`rotate_right()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_right), on the other hand, is a method of slices.

[`Vec<T>` derefs to `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods-%5BT%5D), so most of the time this does not matter. But actually, while this call:

```rust
vec.resize(vec.len(), 0);
```

Desugars to something like:

```rust
<Vec<i32>>::resize(&mut vec, <Vec<i32>>::len(&vec), 0);
```

This call:

```rust
vec.rotate_right(vec.len());
```

Is more like:

```rust
<[i32]>::rotate_right(
    <Vec<i32> as DerefMut>::deref_mut(&mut vec),
    <Vec<i32>>::len(&vec),
);
```

But in what order?

This is the [MIR](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/04/19/MIR.html) for `rotate_right()` (simplified a lot):

```
fn foo() -> () {
    _4 = <Vec<i32> as DerefMut>::deref_mut(move _5);
    _6 = Vec::<i32>::len(move _7);
    _2 = core::slice::<impl [i32]>::rotate_right(move _3, move _6);
}
```

And this is the MIR for `resize()` (again, simplified a lot):

```
fn foo() -> () {
    _4 = Vec::<i32>::len(move _5);
    _2 = Vec::<i32>::resize(move _3, move _4, const 0_i32);
}
```

In the `resize()` example, we first call `Vec::len()` with a reference to `vec`. This returns `usize`. Then we call `Vec::resize()`, when we have no outstanding references to `vec`, so mutably borrowing it is fine!

However, with `rotate_right()`, first we call `<Vec<i32> as DerefMut>::deref_mut(&mut vec)`. This returns `&mut [i32]`, with its lifetime tied to `vec`. That is, as long as this reference (mutable reference!) is alive, we are not allowed to use have any other reference to `vec`. But then we try to borrow `vec` in order to pass the (shared, but it doesn't matter) reference to `Vec::len()`, while we still need to use the mutable reference from `deref_mut()` later, in the call to `<[i32]>::rotate_right()`! This is an error.

This is because Rust defines [an evaluation order for operands](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order-of-operands):

> Expressions taking multiple operands are evaluated left to right as written in the source code.

Because `vec.resize()` is actually `(&mut *vec).rotate_right()`, we first evaluate the dereference+reference, then the arguments:

```rust
let dereferenced_vec = &mut *vec;
let len = vec.len();
dereferencec_vec.rotate_right(len);
```

Which is obviously a violation of the borrow rules.

On the other hand, `vec.resize(vec.len())` has no work to do on the callee (`vec`), and so we first evaluate `vec.len()`, and then the call itself.

Solving this is as easy as extracting the `vec.len()` to a new line (new statement, to be precise), and the compiler also suggests that.

Comment: Why can't the order be swapped? First params and then callee?

Comment: Why can't, or why it wasn't defined this way?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh that would cause `a().b().c().d(param_func())` to evaluate `param_func()` first - I don't think anyone wants that

Answer (score 8):

The only structural difference between these two calls is the target: `rotate_right()` is defined on a slice, while `resize()` is defined on a `Vec`. This means that the non-working case has an additional `Deref` coercion (in this case `DerefMut`) that must pass the borrow checker.

This is actually outside the realm of non-lexical lifetime rules since *how long* the references live is not important. This curiosity would fall under [evaluation order](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order-of-operands) rules; more specifically, given `vec.rotate_right(vec.len())`, when does the coercion from `&mut Vec<_>` to `&mut [_]` occur? Before or after `vec.len()`?

Evaluation order for function and method calls is **left-to-right**, so the coercion must be evaluated before the other parameters, meaning `vec` is already mutably borrowed before `vec.len()` is called.

Comment: This evaluation order bugs me a lot by making me write a single line of code in two lines. Any example of where this order is beneficial or evaluating parameters first is unsafe ?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh honestly, evaluating the callee last wouldn't make sense. A method chain like this `self.f()?.g()?.calculate(expensive_call())` is equivalent to `Type::calculate(self.f()?.g()?, expensive_call())` so `self.f()?.g()?` is the expression for the callee, but you want `expensive_call()` to be evaluated first? Even when there are early-exits available from the `?` operator? Expressions can be complicated, so its more reasonable to have rules set to match the programmers' expectations: that code roughly runs in the order it is written. You can re-order it yourself if needed.

Comment: @kmdreko OTOH it's unintuitive because `resize` does work, even though if the callee is evaluated first it "should". In fact looking at the MIR it first takes a mutable reference to the vector, *then takes an immutable one and gets the length*. I guess this works fine because that doesn't actually call anything and doesn't cross a basic block boundary, but still it does make for a very unintuitive behaviour.

Comment: @Masklinn oh I agree. Just because there's a reason for it doesn't mean it isn't unintuitive.

Comment: @Masklinn Yes, IMO if methods like `resize` could work, means that the evaluation of `&mut self` happens later. If it's designed deliberately, there's no reason to not do the same for `Deref`.

Comment: I guess, in a way, it's consistent. In `foo.bar(foo.baz())`, first callee is resolved i.e. `foo.bar` and then arg `foo.baz()` and hence disallowed.